# how to create exe in desktop application in .net?

Tags: c#-3.0, c#-2.0

I want to create an exe for my C# desktop application.

Actually I don't know how to create.

So please give me some instruction.

Thank you.

Comment: Build the application and find the executable file in PROJECTDIR\bin\YOURCONFIG(ex. Release, Debug)\

Comment: @fardjad:hello Mr see below link.I wants this type of ans not type of your ans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Visual Studio, Right click on Your project under Solution explorer, Build your project, See if any error is their,

**Step 1**

Right Clk solution explorer and `new project` **-->>** `SetUp and Development` **-->>** `Setup Project`

[image]

**Step 2**

Right `project Setup` **-->>** `Add` **-->>** `Project Output`

[image]

**Step 3**

In dialog Box select **Primary Output** and click ok.

[image]

**Step 5**

Now in solution explorer right click your `Setup project` ie(Setup1)  and select `Build`, it will created  exe, msi.

Comment: :But Project output folder what i can add?

Comment: sing:thank you very much my Setup is created but when i run my application and enter data in to Log In form at that time it give a error like "object reference is not set of object".Now i am confused what is going on any file is missing or any anything other.

Comment: @Mansinh: yes you mst be missing some file,folder,assembly, paste your solution explorer image so i can try something